# Integration by parts which contains $(1-x^2)$

Tags: calculus, integration

Are my steps to integrate by parts this function correct :

$$F(x)=\int_{-1}^x{c(1-x^2)}dx$$

$$F(x)=c\int_{-1}^x{(1-x^2)}dx$$

let $u$ = $1 - x^2$

$$\frac{du}{dx} = -2x$$

$$\frac{dx}{du} = \frac{1}{-2x}$$

As

$$\int f(x)dx=\frac{dx}{du}du$$

then :

$$F(x)=c\int_{-1}^x{(1-x^2)}\frac{1}{-2x}$$

This is my primary source of information for this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SP-httjhV0U

Comment: You're integrating over $x$ from $-3/2$ to $x$? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Mattos please see update.

Comment: It _still_ doesn't make sense. You can't have $x$ as the variable you are integrating _and_ have $x$ in the limits of the integrand. You changed the one thing in your original problem that _didn't_ matter.

Comment: That's *not* integration by parts, but by substitution And it doesn't work. Besides, you're making several errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid confusion let us change the dummy variable to $t$ and get $$F(x)=\int_{-1}^x{c(1-t^2)}dt$$

If you insist on integration by parts , let  $u=1-t^2$ and $dv = dt$

We have $ du=-2t dt$ and $v=t$

Thus the integration by part gives us   $$F(x)=\int_{-1}^x{c(1-t^2)}dt = c t(1-t^2)|_{-1}^x-c\int_{-1}^x t(-2t)dt$$

The rest is straight forward.